# Caching entity framework entities between http redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

In my ASP.Net MVC project I cache some entities that are used frequently (like the current user), the problem is that, between redirects (like when I use `RedirectToAction` action result) my DbContext is recreated (because it is created in request scope), and the previously cached entity now does not belongs to the newly created DbContext and I get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Any idea on how can I cache entity framework entities *beside detaching and attaching them each time*?

I don't cache the `DbContext`, just entities.

Comment: I find a very bad idea holding a DbContext in memory...

Comment: No. The issue I suspect is because the OP is caching an `Entity`. Then I suspect he tries to lazy load from the object in another request. To do this, the OP needs to attach to the new `DbContext`.

Comment: First I don't cache DbContext, just the entity, as @Aron said when lazy loading the entity properties the original DbContext is no longer available. The problem to attaching to the new DbContext is that my caching mechanism is not aware of the DbContext

Comment: @mohas In general I find lazy loading to be an anti pattern. I would suggest you avoid using Lazy Loading in your code, period. Entities can only be attached to a single DbContext, so you will find that any attempt to "fix" this will result in concurrency issues. You could try a singleton pattern with the DbContext, but DbContext is designed to be a short lived object, and will cause concurrency and performance issues as a singleton.